# I have 5 IP addresses and use opensmtpd as the mail server on Debian 8.3. The mail server uses the main IP as standard

Tags: debian, openbsd

I have 8 IP addresses on my RootServer, and use OpenSMTPD as the mail server on Debian 8.3. The mail server uses the main IP as standard Ip. How can I tell the mail server www.OpenSMTPD.org to use a different IP, and not the standard IP?

Thank you in advance
Vim

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the domains MX DNS setting in order to have other MTAs use different addresses for that domain.